# WPF Creating a base UserControl that can be used to extend another UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm quite new to WPF and I wanted to create a base UserControl, thats reusable.

For example I've got this UserControl: **TestBase**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.TestBase"
             xmlns=""
             xmlns:x=""
             xmlns:mc="" 
             xmlns:d="" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Style="{StaticResource TestBaseDefault}"
             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Base Text" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

The UserControl **TestBase** is using this Style (TestBaseDefault):

```xml
<Style x:Key="TestBaseDefault" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" Padding="10">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I wanted to create a second UserControl that extends from the **TestBase**.

Which curerntly looks like this: **Test1**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.Test1"
                xmlns=""
                xmlns:x=""
                xmlns:mc="" 
                xmlns:d="" 
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControls"
                x:Name="self"
                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <Grid>

        <TextBlock Text="Overriden Text" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

*Had to remove the links from the UserControls, else I couldnt publish the question.*

What I want to know, is it possible to extend the Test1 from the **TestBase** instead of the **UserControl**, so that I can access the properties from the base, use the Style from it and override the default content?

If not, is there some other way it can be achieved?

Comment: I would suggest using composition instead of inheritance to reuse wpf controls. You can create a control that exposes dependency properties, including things like "content" that is put somewhere inside your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class should be defined as a class without any XAML:

```
public class TestBase : UserControl
{
    public TestBase()
    {
        Style = FindResource("TestBaseDefault") as Style;
    }
}
```

You can then use it as the base class for `Test1`.

**Test1.xaml:**

```
<local:TestBase x:Class="WpfApp1.Test1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>

        <TextBlock Text="Overriden Text" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
</local:TestBase>
```

**Test1.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class Test1 : TestBase
{
    public Test1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

You cannot override a template so the template you have defined in `TestBase.xaml` should be removed or merged into the template that the style defines.

Comment: That worked for me, great solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is related to style in your question(to that exact control) you should define a default style of the base control and set your text property(whatever you want). You don’t need to create a c# base control class unless you explicitly need it because of some requirement.

If you want to use or to override the style of the base contol just use this when defining it:

```
BasedOn=TestBaseDefault
```

So,  base style is:

```
<Style x:Key="TestBaseDefault" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" 
Value="Top"/>
        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" Padding="10">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And for the second control use this:

```
<Style x:Key="OtherControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TestBaseDefault}" >
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
       
    </Style>
```

It will use the default style and your new overriden values.

Finally, set the style to controls:

```
    <TextBox Text="Base Text"                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"                          Foreground="White" 
Style="{StaticResource TestBaseDefault}"/>
```

and the second and all others as well…

```
<TextBox Text="Overriden Text"                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"     VerticalAlignment="Center"
Foreground="White"
Style="{StaticResource     OtherControlStyle}"/>
```

ps: HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAligment, Foreground should be defined in styles and not directly on control but off course overriding some property is allowed there too but there is no point to have two values for the same control at two places.
And make sure that you reference them well…